# How to perform translation from RAW SQL to django queryset

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I am struggling with conversion to django query having raw sql
I am new in django and any help will be appreciated

There are simple models:

Winemaker - target model

Wine

Post

Winemaker has 1+ Wines

Wine has 1+ Posts

I know that it should be done with annotations but have no idea how to implement it.

```
select w2.*,
       (select count(wp.id)
        from web_winemaker www
                 inner join web_wine ww on www.id = ww.winemaker_id
                 inner join web_post wp on ww.id = wp.wine_id
           where
                ww.status=20
            and
                 wp.status=20
            and
                 www.id = w2.id
       ) as wineposts_count,
       (
           select count(w.id)
           from web_winemaker www1
           inner join web_wine w on www1.id = w.winemaker_id
           where
                w.status=20
           and www1.id = w2.id
        ) as wines_count
from web_winemaker w2;
```

Comment: Can you add your models to your question and describe your desired output with examples if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a [Count aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#id8) expression in an annotate function. I took a guess at your `related_name` values on your relationship fields, so the following code may not plug in directly, but should give you an idea of how to do what you want.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

wine_makers = Winemaker.objects.annotate(
    posts_count=Count(
        'wine__post__id',
        filter=Q(wines__status=20, wines__posts__status=20),
    ),
    wines_count=Count(
        'wines__id',
        filter=Q(wines__status=20),
    ),
)
```

You may need to supply `distinct=True` depending on if you're crossing relationships.

Comment: Thank you man! So reactive and great fit answer, yes related_name was `wines` and `posts`.